# Scala generated byte code to Java code conversion

Tags: java, scala, jvm, bytecode, decompiler

I know both Scala & Java generates Byte code from its respective compilers, which can be understood by **JVM**.

But is there any way i can **write Scala code** and **compile it** with Scala compiler and **generate Byte code** and then using any **Java decompiler** we can **generate respective Java code**? Or **vice versa**.

Is there any tools exists to do this? Is it possible to do this conversion? If not can you explain me why it is not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If scala uses certain features that can not be expressed in Java but only in a class file, you might be out of luck. Such features are e.g. invokedynamic, illegal member names, no constructor...

Comment: The question whether there are “*any tools … to do this?*” is very strange as you already decomposed the task into steps, you know the tools for. “write Scala code and compile it with Scala compiler”, of course, you can. Just use the Scala compiler. Use a “Java decompiler” to “generate respective Java code”, well you already named the tool. Whether the result will be convincing, well, that’s subjective, so why don’t you try and judge yourself. On my attempts, Java decompilers did not even convince me regarding decompiling Java code, so I’d expect the result to be disastrous for Scala code…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala compiles to ordinary Java bytecode, so there is nothing stopping you from running a regular Java decompiler on it. However, Java decompilers are optimized for decompiling Java code, so the results you get may not be pretty. In particular, you won't see any of Scala's syntax sugar for obvious reasons.

I am not aware of any dedicated Scala decompilers. As Scala is far more complex, it would be a difficult undertaking to write one.

Comment: As an additional note to this: I was doing some class instrumentation in bytecode and looked at applying it to Groovy class files. Looking at Groovy-generated bytecode, I found it to be... a mess. It was very complex and full of calls to synthetic methods and classes. In one case, I found unreachable bytecode at the end of a method (not sure why it was even emitted by the compiler). The decompilation of this bytecode would likely be incomprehensible.